# How do I check if there is an element in a Matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, matrix

I'm Trying to check in my matrix of dimension [10][10], which spots are available to store data (String) there and which are occupied.

The code basically goes through the whole matrix and checks every spot.

I have tried using the `strlen` and `!= NULL` but everything just prints that the spot is free.

```
char parque[10][10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        parque[i][j] = "";
    }
}

parque[5][5]="f47ac10b-58cb-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d499,ANR";

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if(parque[i][j] != "") {
            printf("The Spot [%d][%d] is taken",i,j);
        } else {
            printf("The Spot [%d][%d] is free",i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the spot [5][5] should print that it's taken, at least that's what I want it to do...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anything else aside, you set `parque[5][5]` to a value, then in the double `for` loops immediately afterwards set everything in `parque` to `""`, spot `[5][5]` is no longer taken.

Comment: I miss edited, the program that I'm running I set to that value afterwards setting everything to ""

Comment: How come this is tagged C if it's JS?

Comment: What? It's C...

Comment: In C, and C++, the line `char[] parque[10][10];` is an error. It must read `char parque[10][10];`. What language are you writing in?

Comment: Additionally, you cannot set an element of a `char` array to a string, as long as this element is not a `char` array itself. Each element of a `parque` is an array of 5 characters. Therefore, you could do  `parque[5] = "abcd";` or `parque[5][5] = 'f';`, but not `parque[5][5] = "abc";`.

Comment: It's C but I don't know how to put it as an array of chars in a matrix... or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration

```
char parque[10][10];
```

declares a two-dimensional array of `char`. If you compile your code with a strict compiler, you'll get an error:

```
error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             parque[i][j] = "";
                          ^
```

What you did mean is to make an array of pointers to `const char`, like here:

```
const char* parque[10][10];
```

Then your program will say that `The Spot [5][5] is taken`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `!=`. You need to use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). And, of course, you need to initialize your array content *before* iterating it and using its values to compare with `""` string.

This condition:

```
if(parque[i][j] != "")
```

Will become:

```
if (strcmp(parque[i][j], ""))
```

Comment: I changed to if (strcmp(parque[i][j], "")) , but it then results in segmentation fault (Core Dumped), I'm using a virtual machine that shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: your matrix elements are uninitialized, if you are lucky, they are NULL. Make sure to initialize and check for NULL.

Comment: @MyNameJeff you are getting the SEGMENTATION FAULT because your MATRIX needs to be initialized.